# Pygame key pressed down

Tags: python, pygame

in the following loop in **pygame**
I made the following loop to check for key presses.
How do I use pygame to check if the key is still being pressed & how often the action will be repeated? For example, if I want that for every second the down key is pressed - it'll repeat the `print("something")` command a variable amount of times.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                print("something")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set a boolean to true in your key down handler and then to false in a new key up handler. Something like:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                down_pressed = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                down_pressed = False

if down_pressed:
  print("Down is pressed")
```

You can then use that boolean in your game logic, for examplemoving a character. `if down_pressed: move_character_down()`

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work! How do I control the amount of times it prints "down is pressed"(for example, if I want it to only print 5 times every second or so)

Comment: This spreads out into another question I think. If this is about moving a character I would: 1. limit the framerate the game runs at (30 or 60), pygame has the tools for this, 2. save the milliseconds since last frame that you get from previous, 3. use that number with a distance = speed * time formula to move the character. (pygame.clock is the module you want)

Answer (score 1):

There is function [pygame.key.get_pressed()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) which gives list of boolean values for all keys.

You can check

```
 pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

 if pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
     print("Down is pressed")
```

But ... probably you have to call `pygame.event.get()` to get actual values from this function.

And ... PyGame doc:

> rapidly pushed keys can be completely unnoticed between two calls

And ... there was one question on SO with problem with this list because it didn't keep information for more then two keys.

So I prefer @will solution :)

--

You can use

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:

    print("Hello World")

    clock.tick(5)
```

to get this text 5 times every second - but other function in `while True`  will be called 5 times every second too. You get 5 FPS.

You can use [pygame.time.get_ticks()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks)  to get time in milliseconds and use it to control only `print()`

```
next_print = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 1000/5 # 1000ms = 1s

while True:

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    if current_time >= next_print:

         print("Hello World")

         next_print += 1000/5
```